# Vim global search in a project

Tags: ubuntu, vim, file-search

I started using vim two weeks ago switching from sublime and I am a ruby developer
I know for a fact that Ack and Ag work very good on a Mac while they're not optimized for my Ubuntu machine.

These are the steps I usually follow when I want to search for words in my project folder (methods, variables, whatever) using "git grep" to search in all of the files in my project folder that contains those words, but it feels a very slow to me to:

1) *Copy the words I want to search, from one file opened in vim* 
2) Ctrl + Z *to send vim in background and use the console*
3) git grep 'what I want to search' ***to actually perform the global search***
4) *Copy the file path from the list of results* 
5) fg to resume *vim from background* 
6) :e filepath *in vim*

What do you use in your environments? 
And what is your opinion about this topic?

Comment: Can you be more specific on what you want to do?

Comment: I just edited the description. Is it clear?

Comment: You need to start using multiple panels @Barbared. I find `vim` with `tmux` ideal. Although `vim` provides multiple panes and windows as well, and there is a terminal implementation for `vim` I believe, I still find it simpler just to use `tmux` so I have multiple shell windows and panes and can run as many instances of `vim` and other commands that I wish in the various panes I've set up. Random search result: https://www.bugsnag.com/blog/tmux-and-vim/

Answer (score 1):

You might want to have a look at fugitive: https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive . You could use the `:Ggrep string` command, what would merge steps 2, 3 and 5 of your example.

See this link for more details on `:Ggrep`: http://vimcasts.org/episodes/fugitive-vim-exploring-the-history-of-a-git-repository/

Answer (score 1):

Here are some alternatives you might want to check:

1. [ack-grep](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/ack-grep)
2. [greplace.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1813)
3. [grep.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=311)

I use the built-in `:vimgrep` command, it just works for me. For external tools I prefer `ack` though.